# Parallel I/O and Retry Logic for Error Handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling, io, plinq

Normally parallel processing is relevant only to CPU intensive operations.  However, PLINQ specifically provides IO-intensive support using the WithDegreeOfParallelism extension.  For example:

```
from site in new[]
{
    "www.albahari.com",
    "www.linqpad.net",
    "www.oreilly.com",
    "www.takeonit.com",
    "stackoverflow.com",
    "www.rebeccarey.com"  
}
.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(6)
let p = new Ping().Send (site)
select new
{
    site,
    Result = p.Status,
    Time = p.RoundtripTime
}
```

But if [supporting IO is the goal of WithDegreeOfParallelism](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Calling_Blocking_Functions_PLINQ), how then can PLINQ be further extended or used to achieve a "retry" effect, which is typical of IO operations?  And what about a "delay" effect?

For example, if IO through a WCF service call throws a CommunicationException, I might want the same request made again with a "3 tries" strategy before moving on to the next resource.  I might also want a minute wait between each try.  And while I "wait" for a minute between each try, I don't want a thread blocked waiting.

In this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/04/9857477.aspx) the author starts with a query similar to what I've shown above.  He then transforms the query so that no threads are blocking.  Unfortunately he lost the WithDegreeOfParallelism in the process.  And either way, he did not address the issue of "retries" when an error occurs.

Anyone have or know of a slick way of doing this?

I was thinking of making a special IEnumerable wrapper that permitted values to be "re-inserted" while the collection was being walked by PLINQ.  This would indeed cause a "retry" behavior, but it would still not allow for the "1 minute delay between retries" requirement.  I could create the 1 minute delay with Thread.Sleep(), but I'm trying not to block threads.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The article you [linked](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/04/9857477.aspx) actually shows how to avoid blocking threads for IO-bound operations by using a `Task`-based API (`DownloadDataTask`) instead:

> However, there’s still something about this code that is not ideal. 
>   The work (sending off download requests and blocking) requires almost
>   no CPU, but it is being done by ThreadPool threads since I’m using the
>   default scheduler.  Ideally, threads should only be used for CPU-bound
>   work (when there’s actually work to do).

Using PLINK / `Task.Run`/ `Task.Factory.StartNew` for IO-based operations is an **anti-pattern**. PLINQ (same as `Parallel.For` etc) is good for CPU-bound computational work, but there is no point in allocating and blocking a thread for a naturally asynchronous network/IO-bound operation, which doesn't need a thread at all while "in-flight". To follow the sample code you showed, that would be something like `new Ping().SendAsync(site)`, returning a `Task`. You could then do `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` and process the errors.

Refer to ["There Is No Thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) by Stephen Cleary, and his recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22232406/1768303) addressing the max degree of parallel IO. On top of that, it's quite easy to incorporate a retry logic, without getting any threads involved (for example, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21326957/1768303)).

Comment: Yes the article's final example does show how to have non-blocking threads, but it omits WithDegreeOfParallism() which means it could cause hundreds of IO calls to be made when in fact I may have wanted only and exactly 5 outstanding IO requests.  Also, PLINQ for IO may be an anti-pattern, but they are encouraging the anti-pattern by offering the WithDegreeOfParallelism() extension.  I edited my question; please see the link I provided that explains WithDegreeOfParallelism was designed for blocking IO.

Comment: @Brent Don't forget that PLINQ was designed before async-await.

Comment: @BrentArias, this maybe OK for a client side app, but for a server-side app +5 more threads per request may easily kill the scalability. You write *"I could create the 1 minute delay with Thread.Sleep(), but I'm trying not to block threads."* So why would you block them with synchronous IO calls, while you can use `async/await`? This is not much different.